# What's the best way to wrap Redux's API so that store instances are transient instead of singletons?

Tags: javascript, node.js, redux, lifetime, lifetime-scoping

I haven't had a look at the source in-depth or anything yet, but was just curious if anyone has required or made use of this in the past or not.

It appears as though Redux is creating a singleton instance for the store and persisting this for the lifetime of the caller, but this is not really tenable for what we're thinking of implementing... what is the simplest approach, if one exists, for extending their API and creating stores with scoped lifetimes?

This is in the context of Redux being used in a purely server-side application (or at least as far as it can tell etc.)

Edit:

> Similarly, while you can reference your store instance by importing it
> directly, this is not a recommended pattern in Redux. If you create a
> store         instance and export it from a module, it will become a
> singleton. This means it     will be harder to isolate a Redux app as
> a component of a larger app, if this is     ever necessary, or to
> enable server rendering, because on the server you want to     create
> separate store instances for every request.

I found this excerpt in their documentation [here](https://redux.js.org/faq/store-setup).

How does this module exporting consideration work in practice? If I only access the store within the scope I declared it for a given lifetime via externally exposed methods, should I expect the instance to be deallocated when the scope closes in some specified app lifetime?

Comment: You should checkout the nextjs framework and especially `next-redux-wrapper`. It keeps the redux store a singleton on the client and dynamically makes stores for each request on the server. Pretty cool in my opinion.

Comment: "*It appears as though Redux is creating a singleton instance for the store and persisting this for the lifetime of the caller*" - no, you're creating the store instance yourself [here](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/essentials/part-2-app-structure#creating-the-redux-store) and then provide it to all components [there](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/essentials/part-2-app-structure#providing-the-store).

Comment: "*If I only access the store within the scope I declared it for a given lifetime via externally exposed methods*" - it's unclear what you mean by "externally exposed methods" here. Store are subject to garbage collection just like any other JavaScript object, references to them govern their lifetime.